What is the maximum number of edges in a graph with n vertices and this restriction on its subgraphs?
The Problem: Given a graph $G$ with $n$ vertices, find the maximum number of edges if each subgraph of $G$ contains a vertex of degree no more than $k$.
I'm looking for either a combinatorial proof or a graph theory proof, which is the reason I've put both tags.
After a brief research, I suspect it's a variant of a handshake lemma, but because of the bounding I am not sure.

What is your definition of subgraph? because technically, $G$ is a subgraph of itself. Also, removing a single edge is a subgraph (if you don't talk about induced subgraph)

Anyway, in all the cases (if $n$ is big enough), the extremal graph is a complete graph on $n-1$ vertices and an isolated vertex linked to $k$ other vertices.

@caduk My understanding of subgraph is that a subgraph is a graph formed from a subset of the vertices and edges of a given graph.

Yeah, and with that definition, $G$ is a subgraph of $G$, which makes the question trivial and the notion of subgraph irrelevant.

@caduk So it has $k + ((n-1)(n-2)/2)$ edges ?

Yes, this is the biggest graph with a vertex of degree $\leq k$.

@caduk But in your graph, there are subgraphs that don't have vertices of degree $\le k$: for example, the subgraph consisting just of the clique with $n-1$ vertices. Each subgraph of $G$ is required to satisfy the condition, not just one subgraph.

@MishaLavrov  Oh, right, I'm completely wrong on this one.

@MishaLavrov I think, technically, for the graph to be the biggest graph possible, we should somehow 'reconstruct' the graph, utilizing the condition: start from $k$ vertices, and keep adding a vertex until you reach $n$ vertices. Each vertex should be connected to any $k$ past vertices. So I guess it might be $k(n-k+1)$?

@Rusurano You are right about the construction, but because the first $k$ vertices can't be connected to $k$ past vertices, you're not quite right about the number of edges.

One extremal construction is to line the $n$ vertices up in a line, and say that each vertex is adjacent to the vertices up to $k$ steps away along the line. In this construction, for every subgraph we take, its rightmost vertex will have degree at most $k$, because its only neighbors in the subgraph will be to its left.
For $n \le k$, this construction is optimal because it ends up being a clique. For $n\ge k+1$, this construction has $\binom k2 + k(n-k)$ edges. (The first $k$ vertices form a clique, and then each of the remaining $n-k$ vertices has $k$ edges to the previous vertices.) We can prove that this is optimal by induction on $n$, starting with $n=k+1$.
When $n=k+1$, we can still take a clique, and this has $\binom{k+1}2 = \binom k2 + k$ edges, as desired.
For $n>k+1$, apply the degree condition to $G$ itself, learning that there is a vertex $v$ of degree at most $k$. Then $G-v$ is a graph with $n-1$ vertices and the same property, so $G-v$ has at most $\binom k2 + k(n-1-k)$ edges. Adding $v$ back in, we get at most $k$ new edges, for a total of $\binom k2 + k(n-k)$, which was what we wanted.

We can add that graphs with this property are $k$-degenerate graphs https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degeneracy_(graph_theory), and $k$-trees https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-tree are extremal
